# Never ending site creation

Tags: sharepoint-online, provisioning, classic

I tried creating a Classic team site a couple months ago and it's still spinning in the Admin Center with the message:

> ```
> We're still working on it and it might take 24 hours
> ```

It seems like this will never go away until I force stop it. Is there a way to cancel this site creation and remove this message?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform Test-SPOSite command to know whether those site collection is created under your tenant, if you get any unknown error then you can conclude that those site collection are not created successfully.

Test-SPOSite -Identity https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollectionname

So you need to contact Microsoft to delete those site collection from your admin center.

About how to create service requests to contact Office 365 support:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenkumar/2013/07/17/how-to-create-service-requests-to-contact-office-365-support/

Comment: I'm off until Monday, but will try this and check back with you.

Comment: I get Test-SPOSite : Unknown Error

Comment: Contacted support and they couldn't delete it. Basically said Classic is going away so just leave it *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you tried to create the site from the Central Administration .

The best way to delete this site would be first go to the Manage content databases in the Central Administration , make the database read only .

Then go to the ssms, remove the database .

After this try to recreate the site using powershell .

Note :- Make sure that you have only this particular site in the content database. Otherwise if you are hosting multiple sites in content database all those sites will get deleted.

Comment: Hi Yash, OP is asking about SharePoint Online and solution you have given is for SharePoint OnPrem.

Comment: I'm using SP Online, but thanks for making me realize how much I don't miss on-prem!